# How to upgrade dependencies added by create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app

When and how can we upgrade the dependencies that `create-react-app` adds to `package.json`?

Today I ran `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` and it added these dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  }
```

Even though some have newer versions available:

- "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4"
- "@testing-library/react": "^11.0.4"
- "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.6"
- "typescript": "~4.0.3"

Can we upgrade any dependency at any time or are they tied to the specific version of `react-scripts`? If it is the latter how do we know when to upgrade and what version to upgrade to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When?

I'm still figuring that out, but maybe when a dependency (e.g. @testing-library/user-event) strongly recommends updating.

> and how

Here is a walkthrough of how to update dependencies. Your mileage may vary. I recommend testing each change before moving to the next. Some dependencies may need to go together.

I recently (2022) ran `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` and analyzing the dependencies with `npm outdated` for me shows:

```bash
Package                      Current  Wanted  Latest
@testing-library/user-event   13.5.0  13.5.0  14.4.3
@types/jest                   28.1.8  28.1.8  29.1.2
@types/node                  18.7.14  18.8.3  18.8.3
web-vitals                     2.1.4   2.1.4   3.0.3
```

## Major version upgrades:

You can see that `@testing-library/user-event` does not "want" a higher version, but a higher MAJOR version does exist.
In order to upgrade major versions, which in theory does not happen as frequently as minor versions, I use a brute force method which involves `npm uninstall <package-name>` and then `npm install <package-name>`.

For package `@testing-library/user-event`,

```bash
# show the version installed
npm list | grep '@testing-library/user-event'
npm uninstall -D @testing-library/user-event
npm list | grep '@testing-library/user-event'
npm uninstall -D @testing-library/user-event
npm list | grep '@testing-library/user-event'
```

The following is printed for the above commands

```bash
  ├── @testing-library/user-event@13.5.0

  ├── @testing-library/user-event@14.4.3
```

Executing `npm outdated` again shows `@testing-library/user-event` is omitted. Success!

```bash
Package      Current  Wanted  Latest
@types/jest   28.1.8  28.1.8  29.1.2
@types/node  18.7.14  18.8.3  18.8.3
web-vitals     2.1.4   2.1.4   3.0.3
```

## Minor version upgrades:

Updating a package to a higher minor version can be accomplished using [npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-update).

You can see that `@types/node` has a higher MINOR version available that `npm outdated` marks as `Wanted`. You can upgrade any single package wanting a MINOR upgrade by saying `npm update <package-name>`, or ALL packages wanting a minor upgrade by omitting the package name, e.g. `npm update`

For upgrading only package `@types/node`,

```bash
npm update @types/node
npm outdated
```

Running the commands above show `@types/node` is no longer "Wanted" to upgrade, visible in the following output. Success!

```bash
Package      Current  Wanted  Latest
@types/jest   28.1.8  28.1.8  29.1.2
web-vitals     2.1.4   2.1.4   3.0.3
```

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed answer. My question was trying to ask whether or not it is OK to manually upgrade the dependencies added by create-react-app or if it should be done in some other way (maybe some create-react-app-upgrade command or something). Based on your writeup I guess the answer is "Yes, manually upgrade." Thank you!

Comment: @MikeVosseller I had the same question, and this is how I determined the answer is "yes". :)

Comment: @MikeVosseller I think the upgrade is "manual" because it is "opt in/your choice/YMMV". Notice I'm making sure each dependency update works before moving onto the next one. I'm not touching "web-vitals" at the moment.